# decimal выдаёт целое число (без запятой)

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу код для этой формулы.

[image: Формула]

Вопрос по отображению результата в decimal.
Нужно, чтобы были знаки после запятой, а выдаёт просто 0.

Product - произведение.

Сложность в том, что некоторые операции требуют только double (степень - Math.Pow), в других нельзя этот double использовать (умножение). Запуталась в преобразованиях.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
            int product = 0;   // тут int, т.к. нельзя умножать decimal
            double Factorial = 1;


            for (double i = 2; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Factorial *= i;
                double vnutriSkobok = Convert.ToDouble(1 - (1 / Factorial)); // double нужнен для Math.Pow

                product = product * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(vnutriSkobok, 2));  // double и decimal не умножает - ошибка

                decimal Product = Convert.ToDecimal(product); // обратно, чтобы были знаки после запятой

                label7.Text = Product.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По моему ошибка была в том, что вы изначально инициализирвовали `product` нулём а потом перемножали его же на коэфициент, а ноль умноженный на что угодно - всё равно ноль.
Преобразовал немного ваш код:

```
decimal product = 1; 
decimal Factorial = 1;

for (decimal i = 2; i <= 3; i++)
{
    Factorial *= i;
    decimal vnutriSkobok = 1 - (1 / Factorial); // double нужнен для Math.Pow

    product = product * Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow((double)vnutriSkobok, 2));  // double и decimal не умножает - ошибка

    label7.Text = product.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Слона и не заметила. 
За (Math.Pow((double)vnutriSkobok... отдельно благодарю. Не знала, что так можно!